# Use UNION with DISTINCT in Laravel Eloquent query builder with relations

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, distinct, union

I have 2 tables,

```
properties
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | null      |
|  2 | 1         |
|  3 | null      |
|  4 | 3         |
|  5 | 3         |
|  6 | null      |
+----+-----------+
```

and

```
sale_services
+----+-------------+------+
| id | property_id | rank |
+----+-------------+------+
|  1 |           2 |    5 |
|  2 |           4 |    4 |
|  3 |           5 |    6 |
|  4 |           6 |    7 |
+----+-------------+------+
```

and corresponding Eloquent Models (**SaleService** and **Property**) linked to each other by relation (*sale_service.property_id = property.id*). **Property** can be linked to another **Property** in the same table.

I need to get a collection of **SaleService** instances, where related `property.parent_id` is null OR if there are some records in `sale_services` table sharing same `parent_id` through `properties` table, distincted by that field and order by `rank`.

a result should be

```
+----+-------------+------+
| id | property_id | rank |
+----+-------------+------+
|  1 |           2 |    5 |
|  3 |           5 |    6 |
|  4 |           6 |    7 |
+----+-------------+------+
```

- all items from `sale_services` table except *(sale_service.id = 2)*, because it's property shares same `parent_id` with item *(sale_service.id = 3)* and item with *(sale_service.id = 3)* has highest `rank` value

I figured out SQL code to get desired result,

```
 SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT ON (properties.parent_id) *
       FROM "sale_services"
       INNER JOIN "properties" ON "sale_services"."property_id" = "properties"."id"
       WHERE ("properties"."parent_id") IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY "properties"."parent_id", "sale_services"."rank" DESC) AS sub
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM "sale_services"
    INNER JOIN "properties" ON "sale_services"."property_id" = "properties"."id"
    WHERE ("properties"."parent_id") IS NULL
```

but I cant reach same with Eloquent Builder.

I tried something like this

```
$queryWithParent = SaleService::query()
    ->select(\DB::raw('DISTINCT ON (properties.parent_id) *'))
    ->whereNotNull('properties.parent_id')
    ->join('properties', 'sale_services.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
    ->orderBy('parent_id')
    ->orderBy('sale_services.index_range', 'desc');

$queryWithoutParent = SaleService::query()
    ->join('properties', 'sale_services.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
    ->whereNull('properties.parent_id');

$query = $queryWithParent->union($queryWithoutParent);
```

but got an error

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "union" LINE 1: ...perties.type <> 'hotel') order by "parent_id" asc union sele... ^ (SQL: select DISTINCT ON (properties.parent_id) * from "sale_services" inner join "properties" on "sale_services"."property_id" = "properties"."id" where ("properties"."parent_id") is not null and ("sale_services"."deleted_at") is null and "published" = 1 and exists (select 1 from "properties" where properties.id = sale_services.property_id AND properties.type <> 'hotel') order by "parent_id" asc union select * from "sale_services" inner join "properties" on "sale_services"."property_id" = "properties"."id" where ("properties"."parent_id") is null and ("sale_services"."deleted_at") is null and "published" = 1 and exists (select 1 from "properties" where properties.id = sale_services.property_id AND properties.type <> 'hotel') order by "index_range" desc limit 12 offset 0)
```

If I remove ordering from first query (**$queryWithParent**) it seems working, but with random item selected in distinct query.

Is there any other way to achieve same result, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exact version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.7, PostgreSQL 10

Comment: What version of Laravel 5.7?

Comment: Laravel version 5.7.15

Comment: The `UNION` issue has been fixed in Laravel 5.7.28: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27589

Comment: Wow, that's really make a difference, thanks! No more need to wrap first query in a subquery.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with a solution, post your solution as an answer instead. Self-answers are encouraged (assuming they follow the same rules as other answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

1. Use Laravel ^5.7.28 (The UNION issue has been fixed in Laravel 5.7.28: [github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27589](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27589)) and you will not need a subquery!
2. Specify table columns to select to avoid column name collision `sale_services.*`

   ```
   $queryWithParent = SaleService::query()
       ->select(\DB::raw('DISTINCT ON (properties.parent_id) sale_services.*'))
       ->from('sale_services')
       ->join('properties', 'sale_services.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
       ->whereNotNull('properties.parent_id')
       ->orderBy('properties.parent_id')
       ->orderBy('sale_services.index_range', 'desc');

   $queryWithoutParent = SaleService::query()
       ->select(\DB::raw('sale_services.*'))
       ->join('properties', 'sale_services.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
       ->whereNull('properties.parent_id');

   $query = $queryWithParent->union($queryWithoutParent);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The laravel query creator for "Distinct" is distinct() as in :

```
$queryWithParent = SaleService::query()
->distinct('properties.parent_id')
->whereNotNull('properties.parent_id')
->join('properties', 'sale_services.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
->orderBy('parent_id')
->orderBy('sale_services.index_range', 'desc');
```

Does that work ?

Comment: As a side-note the equivalent for a collection would be "unique()".

Comment: Eloquent Builder distinct() method have no arguments and is not compatible with PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON operator, so not, it doesn't work...

Comment: You're right, I've tried it in my code and doesn't seem to be useful in your case.
If you don't find a DB way to get your answer and aren't pulling an enormous quantity of data then you can use the collection unique() like I did :

    $db_query->get()->unique('participant_id');

Comment: The problem is that I need huge filtering by ~10-20 params and eager relationship loading after this stage, so collection methods is not a way to go.
Anyway, thank you.
I'm thinking about custom database views now.